# Why are samba client and NFS client used differently?

Tags: samba, nfs, lubuntu

Can you compare why samba client and NFS client are used differently?

For example, Why do I have to  `mount`  a shared directory on a NFS client side, while I don't have to for samba client side?

In pcmanfm, why can I   just type `smb://192.168.1.198` on the address bar of file manager, and connect to samba server, while I can't do similarly to access a NFS shared directory, or how can I?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`pcmanfm` uses `gvfs`, a GNOME Virtual FileSystem. It has SMB support in the `gvfs-backends` package, which depends on `libsmbclient` and suggests `samba-common`.

GVFS requires D-Bus and/or GIO module support for programs to use it, or a `gvfs-fuse` package that uses FUSE to allow mounting GVFS-accessible filesystems to be accessible by generic programs.

Also, a NFS server and client will trust each other on a much deeper level than a SMB server and client, if the classic NFS `sec=sys` security model is used, and so mounting a NFS filesystem must require administrative access. (Think of what you could do as a regular user if you could freely mount a filesystem containing `setuid` binaries of your choice from a server specified by you. The answer is "anything".) That is why implementing a user-accessible `nfs://` protocol would not be trivial.

Comment: Thanks. (1) How can I access a NFS shared irectory in pcmanfm, maybe similarly to a Samba shared directory?  (2) " a NFS server and client will trust each other on a much deeper level than a SMB server and client". But I configured NFS server by `/share 192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)` by following https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-a-nfs-file-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver, It turns out that there is no explicit authentication from a client side (another computer in the same local network).  How can I configure the NFS server so that it can securely share a directory?

Comment: (1) `mount` it as root, or have an admin set up a prepared `/etc/fstab` line that allows user mounting, then use `pcmanfm` to access it like a local filesystem. That is the only way. (2) ...and this is why (1) is so: no authentication, just blind trust. NFSv4 allows secure sharing with Kerberos authentication and optional traffic encryption, but you'll need to set up a Kerberos authentication environment first... and **that** is not exactly trivial.

Comment: "That is the only way" for NFS, whereas "pcmanfm uses gvfs, a GNOME Virtual FileSystem. It has SMB support in the gvfs-backends package, which depends on libsmbclient and suggests samba-common. " Does gvfs, not have NFS support? Surprising if yes, given that NFS seems more native to Linux than Samba is

Comment: Looks like I was wrong... there *is* a NFS backend for GVFS, but it seems to be packaged separately, so it might be still experimental or have other issues with it. The NFS protocol was originally designed for sharing disks between multi-user systems, so it does not quite have a concept of "allow only this one particular user to access the share according to their permissions": the protocol basically allows full access and trusts that the **client** will restrict the client-side users as appropriate. But if the client is evil, it can do anything... the `root_squash` was the first fix for this.

Answer (score 2):

Tim, you ask more than one question. But let me answer one (which I found interesting)

You do not need to mount the NFS share. You can access it on this way:

```
cd /net/<NFS server IP or hostname/path/to/shared/dir
```

and then copy, view, etc. the files and directories inside. You do not need to specity the protocol as this (`/net` ) is a special directory like `/proc` for example. TO use `/net` you need to install `autofs` package.

You can mount SMB share on this way:

```
mount -t cifs -o user=<username> //<IP or hostname of SMB server>/<share name> /mount/point
```

For more details you can check [Samba documentation](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Mounting_samba_shares_from_a_unix_client)

Comment: Thanks. (1) Why is there no protocol name like `nfs://` in the URL in your `cd` command, while I have to type `smb://` in the address bar of a file manager? (2) can you mount a samba shared directory? If yes, how?

Comment: @Tim, you can mount SMB share on the same way you mount filesystem, see my edited answer